# Italian Navy National Service

Tags: military-records, navy, italy

Would like to know where my father Mario Siega served as I am trying to make a family tree and have had a problem finding any information about him. He was born in Trieste Italy in January 1914

Answer (score 1):

A starting point for researching Italian Navy personnel may be [La Regia Marina](http://www.icsm.it/regiamarina/research.htm):

> If the information you are searching for are about a sailor who was
>   your relative, and you know his name and (at least approximately) his
>   place and date of birth the way to follow is to obtain from Italian
>   Navy his service records ("Estratto del foglio matricolare" are named
>   the records in Italian).